# Is there a name for this family of curves?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I saw a space curve defined as the following before (but I don't remember the reference):
$$
\alpha_{p,q}(t)=\{\left((2+\cos pt)\cos qt,(2+\cos pt)\sin qt,\sin pt\right)|t\in{\Bbb R}\}
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.

For example, $\alpha_{5,3}$ is something like
[image]

Is there a name for this family of curves? Would any one come up with a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you've written down a $(p, q)$ torus knot: it runs along the surface of a torus of major radius 2 and minor radius 1, turning p times around the long way and q times the short way (or perhaps vice-versa). A search for "torus knot" will yield a wealth of information.